# How can I make a date table based on several start and end dates on other table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with two columns: start date and end date.
I want to create another table  that contains one column with all the dates from the intervals of the first table. I would like all the  intervals between start dates and end dates, not just the start and end dates.

How can I do this?

I think I should use the CALENDAR function because I have a sart and end date. I think I should use the UNION function to join all the tables from date intervals. But I think I would need some kind of a UNIONX function that does not exist.

Comment: Duplicate the table  with Start Date and End Date then append End Date to Start Date table and then perform remove duplicate on column.

Comment: hello @Mboolean , thank you for your answer. I would like all the dates in the intervals between start dates and end dates, not just start dates and end dates.

Comment: Than you may use something Calendar(Min(Date), Max(Date)) , which populate all dates between your first start date and last end date.

Comment: I would like juste the dates between each interval, not between the first start date and the last end date.

Answer (score 0):

You could just union the two columns into a new table like so:

```
Union Start and End Dates :=
UNION ( VALUES ( 'Table'[StartDate] ), VALUES ( 'Table'[EndDate] ) )
```